# Nanokid in creation

Tags: chemfig, fun

[image]

Hello, I want to create the Nanokid with latex, but I need some help for the hands. How do i create the Hands, where 3 snakes in 3 different direction?

I have this so far

```
$\chemfig{*6(=(-~-*6(=-(-~--[:-90]-[:-150])=-(-~--[:-90]-[:-30])=-))-(-~--)=-(-)=(-~--)-)}$
```

Comment: Please always provide a compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Answer (score 2):

You almost had it:

```
\documentclass[border=10mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand*\printatom[1]{\ensuremath{\mathsf{#1}}}
\footnotesize
\chemfig[atom sep=1.25em]{*6(=(-~-*6(=-(-~--[:-90]-[:-150])=-(-~--[:-90]-[:-30])=-))-(-~-([:30]-)([:-90]-)-)=-(-*5(-O---O-))=(-~-([:210]-)([:90]-)-)-)}

\end{document}
```

[image]